# Laraver DB Query

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent

I am new in Laravel, and I don't know what is happening here. I made a simple join query with two tables, but I get the triple result. I tried with `distinct()`, `orderBy()`(getting an error)... Can someone tell me what is happening here

Laravel Query:

```
    public function getArtForCom($id) {
    $articles = Article::select('kup_art.rbr as id', 'kup_art.sifra as article_id', 'kup_art.naziv as article_name', 'kup_art.grupa as group_id', 'kup_art.grupa_naziv as group_name', 'ro_stanje.koli as count',  'ro_stanje.v_cije as price')
        ->join('ro_stanje', 'kup_art.sifra', 'ro_stanje.sifra')
        ->where('kupac', $id)
        ->get();
    return response()->json($articles);
}
```

and result is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "article_id": "000140",
    "article_name": "KECAP BF",
    "group_id": "04",
    "group_name": "KECEPI  ",
    "count": "130.000",
    "price": "3.590"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "article_id": "000407",
    "article_name": "SWISS ROLS",
    "group_id": "13",
    "group_name": "INDUSTRIJSKI ROLAT",
    "count": "485.000",
    "price": ".790"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "article_id": "000140",
    "article_name": "KECAP BF",
    "group_id": "04",
    "group_name": "KECEPI",
    "count": "266.000",
    "price": "3.050"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "article_id": "000407",
    "article_name": "SWISS ROLS",
    "group_id": "13",
    "group_name": "INDUSTRIJSKI ROLAT",
    "count": "7204.000",
    "price": ".490"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "article_id": "000140",
    "article_name": "KECAP BF",
    "group_id": "04",
    "group_name": "KECEPI  ",
    "count": "3.000",
    "price": "3.215"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "article_id": "000407",
    "article_name": "SWISS ROLS",
    "group_id": "13",
    "group_name": "INDUSTRIJSKI ROLAT",
    "count": "17.000",
    "price": ".490"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "article_id": "000140",
    "article_name": "KECAP BF",
    "group_id": "04",
    "group_name": "KECEPI  ",
    "count": ".000",
    "price": "3.215"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "article_id": "000407",
    "article_name": "SWISS ROLS",
    "group_id": "13",
    "group_name": "INDUSTRIJSKI ROLAT",
    "count": "69.000",
    "price": ".490"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "article_id": "000140",
    "article_name": "KECAP BF",
    "group_id": "04",
    "group_name": "KECEPI  ",
    "count": "2.000",
    "price": "3.215"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "article_id": "000407",
    "article_name": "SWISS ROLS",
    "group_id": "13",
    "group_name": "INDUSTRIJSKI ROLAT",
    "count": "48.000",
    "price": ".490"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "article_id": "000407",
    "article_name": "SWISS ROLS",
    "group_id": "13",
    "group_name": "INDUSTRIJSKI ROLAT",
    "count": "30.000",
    "price": ".488"
  }
]
```

Comment: It seem you forget to add "=" in join. Try this  ->join('ro_stanje', 'kup_art.sifra', '=', 'ro_stanje.sifra')

Comment: i tried...but still nothing...

Comment: i fixed, errro was in database structure. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting duplicate results. The results return the same products, but the variety of price and count:

```
 {
     "id": 1,
     "article_id": "000140",
     "article_name": "KECAP BF",
     "group_id": "04",
     "group_name": "KECEPI  ",
     "count": "130.000",
     "price": "3.590"
  }
```

Count and Price are different:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "article_id": "000140",
    "article_name": "KECAP BF",
    "group_id": "04",
    "group_name": "KECEPI",
    "count": "266.000",
    "price": "3.050"
  },
```

You could add `groupBy('kup_art.sifra')`, but results won't be accurate, so it is better to check in the DB why are there multiple data for price and stock for the same SKU.

Answer (score 0):

You need to groupBy common key here, kup_art.sifra

```
  public function getArtForCom($id) {
$articles = Article::select('kup_art.rbr as id', 'kup_art.sifra as article_id', 
   'kup_art.naziv as article_name', 'kup_art.grupa as group_id', 'kup_art.grupa_naziv as 
   group_name', 'ro_stanje.koli as count',  'ro_stanje.v_cije as price')
    ->join('ro_stanje', 'kup_art.sifra', 'ro_stanje.sifra')
    ->where('kupac', $id)
    ->groupBy('kup_art.sifra')
    ->get();
return response()->json($articles);
 }
```

Comment: Grouping is not the solution since there are variations in count and price for the same SKU